# How can I change background image in html?

Tags: html

I'm new in the html world.
I'm trying to change the background image in html using this code but it doesn't works..

```
<body background="image.jpg" bgcolor="#ffff00">
 my code here
</body>
```

How can I change the background image?

Comment: How is this related to `java`?

Comment: Please add some more description here besides image

Comment: 3 down votes within one minute must feel like swimming in a pool of sharks. To avoid such responses, I propose to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error in line 7:**

You need to use `<body style="background-image: url('sfondo.jpg')">`.
Do remember image location should be on same folder.

Answer (score 1):

There no such attribute for background. You should add it in inline css style. Try inline style like this:

```
<body style='background-image: url("sfondo.jpg");'>
    ------
</body>
```

Refer this for more background options https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask the question properly but I think you asking about java web application development related question from eclipse so I want to share some experience with you. If you are using .jsp(index.jsp) file you can use JSTL or without JSTL to set background as below.

```
<body background="<c:url value='/resources/images/sfondo.jpg' />">
```

or

```
<body background="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/sfondo.jpg">
```

note: I used "resources/images/sfondo.jpg" path you can change it as you need

- First you should refer about proper project structure(eg. how to organize images, web files, java files etc...). If you are doing java dynamic web application development you can keep image files under WebContent folder. If you are using maven, structure it is difference.

If you are using .html(index.html) file you can use css code inside html file to control background image

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("sfondo.jpg");
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
```

or you can use inside body tag too, but I think in some cases it is not working properly.